# Creating a string using onClick and getting the final value to search to the array

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android and I am currently having this problem on `onClick()`:

I have dynamically created textViews within a `TableLayout()` and each textviews have `onClickListener`. The code is like this:

```
text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        //change the color of tapped textview
        text.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        text.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#c04485ed"));

        String a = view.getTag().toString();
        String b = text.getText().toString();

        uTxt.setText(""+uTxt.getText().toString() + b);

        if(uTxt.length() == 4){

            if(checkAns(uTxt, list)){
                Log.e("OUTPUT: " , uTxt.getText().toString().toLowerCase() + " IS ON THE ARRAY!");
            }
            else if (!checkAns(uTxt, list))
            {
                Log.e("OUTPUT: " , uTxt.getText().toString() + " IS NOT ON THE ARRAY!");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I also initialized a method called `checkAns()` and it goes like this:

```
private boolean checkAns(TextView uTxt, List<String> list) {
    String word = uTxt.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
    if (list.contains(word)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The purpose of that method is to catch the created word and check if the formed word is on the array.

But that method always returns `false`. **Is there anything wrong with my logic?**

Any help, comments, and suggestions are welcome. :)

**EDIT:**

@k3b ask me where the `list` is populated. So here is the full code of the `textView` grid that i created:

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl);
    final TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
    table.setTag(1);
    final Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "kg.ttf");
    final Typeface font2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "futura.ttf");
    final String[] wordArray = new String[Category.size];
    final TextView uTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.userTxt);

    for(int i = 0; i < Category.size; i++){
        wordArray[i] = listahan[i];
    }

    final List<String> list = Arrays.asList(wordArray);

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        final LinearLayout rowLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        rowLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        rowLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        final TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
        row.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        row.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        row.setTag(i);

        int k = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < input.length; j++) {
            final TextView text = new TextView(this);
            Character temp = input[i][j];
            text.setText(temp.toString());
            text.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
            text.setTag(i + " " + j);
            text.setTextSize(txtSize);
            text.setTypeface(font);
            text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    //change the color of tapped textview
                    text.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    text.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#c04485ed"));


                    String a = view.getTag().toString();
                    String b = text.getText().toString();

                    uTxt.setText(""+uTxt.getText().toString() + b);

                    if(uTxt.length() == 4){

                        if(checkAns(uTxt, list)){
                            Log.e("OUTPUT: " , uTxt.getText().toString().toLowerCase() + " IS ON THE ARRAY!");
                        }
                        else if (!checkAns(uTxt, list))
                        {
                            Log.e("OUTPUT: " , uTxt.getText().toString() + " IS NOT ON THE ARRAY!");
                        }

                    }


                    }

            });
            text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            row.addView(text);
        }
```

Comment: Add the list you're comparing against to your logging and then provide the output of all of the logs.

Comment: `if(checkAns(uTxt, list))`where is `list`declared and populated?

Comment: @k3b it is initialized inside the method that created those dynamic `textViews` (_see the edit above for clarification_)

Comment: @kpsharp - how should i put that in a code?

Comment: Toggle a breakpoint to check your list and word. send us exact variable (just your list and word)values and i help you solve it soon.

Comment: @Gboy Just loop over your list on the line after `if(uTxt.length() == 4){` and print out each list item like you're doing elsewhere.

After you do that, run it, grab all of the logs, and provide them here.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help guys. I managed to fix the error. It seems that the code that initialized my array of words is not properly coded! Thanks guys!